# Java performs the increment operation after return on object references

Tags: java, return, increment, order-of-execution

I have this code :

```
public class counter {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double[] array = new double[10];
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) array[i] = i;
        printArray(array);
        double result = doSomething(array);
        printArray(array);
    }
    public static void printArray(double[] arr){
        for(double d : arr) System.out.println(d);
    }
    public static double doSomething(double[] array){
        return array[0]++;
    }
}
```

I have learned that after the return statement no more code is executed and the increment++ increments the value at the next expression. So it seems logical to me that the the first element of the array `array[0]` should not be incremented.

However the output array is {1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Comment: Your increment is not _after_ the return statement. It is _inside_ the return statement.

Comment: Is there a question in here? Clearly what seems logical to you is not the case. `variable++` is an expression that yields the value that the variable had before incrementing, and also increments the variable, *before the expression completes*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> after the return statement no more code is executed

That's correct. But the `++` is not *after* the return statement, it's *part of it*.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
int temp = array[0];
array[0] = temp + 1;
return temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The array[0]++ is inclusive in the return statement.
Hence the incremented value is stored in array[0] (i.e array[0] = 1)
Don't confuse yourself thinking that increment will take after return statement as it is post-increment